# My find phone not active in windowsphone.com

Tags: find-my-phone

My Lumia 920 was stolen on Sunday May 31st. I have been trying since then to locate my phone by signing in windowsphone.com using my microsoft account.

I click the "Find My Phone" menu on the right corner of the window, but the "Find My Phone" menu there is not active so I can't make my phone ring, or erase phone.

Is there any other way to erase phone or lock all the data inside?

Comment: Are you sure the Find My Phone feature was active on the phone previously?

Comment: No Neil, unfortunately I just knew that it has to be manually activated. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to enable the feature on the phone when you get it (well, before you lose it/have it stolen).

As with losing any phone, your mobile operator should still be able to at the very least lock the SIM, and issue a replacement to you to avoid incurring any charges by whoever now has your phone.

Comment: Awww.... :'( So they can still grab any information, such as documents, photos, etc. from the phone, even when my mobile operator has locked the SIM?

Comment: Yes, unless you have secured your phone with a pin. Do make sure to change your Microsoft account password so they won't get any mails and can't buy apps etc.

Comment: If you enabled the automatic upload of pictures to OneDrive, you might be able to see where they've taken photos (assuming they haven't just done a hard reset the instant they got hold of it.)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I will make sure that I read all the manual book next time, so this silly thing won't be happened again.